# How can I select the item from the search dropdown and have it populate the search input field

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, bootstrap-5

If you type a word into the search input field a suggestion list appears below.

[image]

I would like to be able to select the word from the list e.g **Maine (ME)** and have it then populate the search input field. How would I manipulate my code to be able to do this please?

**HTML**

```html
<form action="*">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="rounded form-control" id="search" autocomplete="off" 
    placeholder="Current Location">
  </div>
<div id="match-list" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```js
const search = document.getElementById('search');
const matchList = document.getElementById('match-list');

// Search states.json and filter it
const searchPlaces = async searchText => {
    const res = await fetch('../data/states.json');
    const states = await res.json();

    // Get matches to current text input
    let matches = states.filter(state => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
        return state.name.match(regex) || state.abbr.match(regex);
    });

    if (searchText.length === 0) {
        matches = [];
        matchList.innerHTML = '';
    }
    outputHtml(matches);
};

// Show results in HTML
const outputHtml = matches => {
    if (matches.length > 0) {
        const html = matches.map(match => `
        <div class="card card-body mb-1">
        <h6>${match.name} (${match.abbr})</h6>
        </div>
        
        `).join('');
        matchList.innerHTML = html;
    }
};

search.addEventListener('keyup', () => searchPlaces(search.value));

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = "text";
  }
```

**json**

```json
[
    {
        "abbr": "AL",
        "name": "Alabama",
    },
{
        "abbr": "ME",
        "name": "Maine",
    }
]
```

Comment: I see your statement of what you want it to do, but it's unclear if your code is not working.

Comment: It's not working as if you see at the bottom of the javascript code when  myFunction() is called the word "text" only appears in the dev tools Elements tab and not displayed in the search input field on the page.

```<input type="text" class="rounded form-control" id="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Current Location">text</input```

Answer (score 0):

Found I needed to put `value=""` into the html file

```html
 <input type="search" class="rounded form-control" id="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Current Location" value="">
```

and to update the following function in the javascript file.

```js
function myFunction() {
    let texts = document.querySelector("h6").innerText;
    document.getElementById("search").value = texts;
    matchList.innerHTML = '';
  }
```